# WebGet and non WebGet methods in WCF Rest Service

Tags: wcf, rest

Following is my Contract and the OperationContracts, my issue is when I'm going with WebGet attribute to all the methods my service is working fine, when I remove WebGet Attribute to any one of the OperationContracts im getting following error.

> Operation 'ProductDetails' of
>   contract 'IDemo' specifies multiple
>   request body parameters to be
>   serialized without any wrapper
>   elements. At most one body parameter
>   can be serialized without wrapper
>   elements. Either remove the extra body
>   parameters or set the BodyStyle
>   property on the
>   WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to
>   Wrapped.

These are my methods

```
string AddNumbers(int x,int y);  --- using [WebGet]

string SubtractNumbers(int x, int y); -- using [WebGet]

String ProductDetails(string sName, int cost, int Quntity, string binding); -- not using using [WebGet]

CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite); -- not using [WebGet]
```

Is it mandatory to include `[WebGet]` attribute to all the operation contracts if we go for WebHttpbinding??.

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]        
    string GetData(int value,string binding);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
           UriTemplate = "/Add?num1={x}&num2={y}")]
    string AddNumbers(int x,int y);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
           UriTemplate = "/Subtract?num1={x}&num2={y}")]
    string SubtractNumbers(int x, int y);

    [OperationContract]
    String ProductDetails(string sName, int cost, int Quntity, string binding);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message really says exactly what the problem is:

> Operation 'ProductDetails' of contract
>   'IDemo' specifies multiple request
>   body parameters to be serialized
>   without any wrapper elements. **At most
>   one body parameter** can be serialized
>   without wrapper elements.

You cannot have methods which expect more than one parameter, unless you wrap those, e.g. by specifying the `BodyStyle` setting in the `WebGet` attribute.

So yes: either you have to apply a `[WebGet]` to each method of your REST service, or you can reorganize your methods to take in only a single parameter (e.g. by wrapping up the two or three parameters you have now into a single class that holds those multiple parameters, and then passing in an object instance of that Request class).

```
[DataContract]
public class AddNumbersRequest
{
   [DataMember]
   public int X { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public int Y { get; set; }
}   

[OperationContract]
string AddNumbers(AddNumbersRequest request);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply marc,i jus tried with the above implementation that you posted its working good, appreciate it.

Comment: Why did MS allow you to mix OperationContract and Web[Get|Invoke] in the same project but then force every method to play by the Web programming model when you want it to be a SOAP only method? (Yes, I know I'm ranting to the wrong people, but still)

Comment: @thaBadDawg: nobody forces you to take that approach... you can have totally separate SOAP and REST service facades (while possibly sharing common backend code nonetheless). MS needs to make a lot of people with a lot of different opinions about what is "right" happy  ....

Comment: I took the two different facades route. It doesn't seem very DRY to have to do that to satisfy the two RPC types. Minor annoyance, was just hoping to avoid having two classes for essentially the same purpose.